# JS Regex Positive Lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split a string by space. But without removing it and it should be added to the previous string and not to the next.

As you see in the `result` the space got added to the next word.

Here is my [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WQ9EU0/1/).

#### Regex:

`/(?=\040)/g`

#### Result:

"Lorem| ipsum| dolor| si| amet."

#### What I need

"Lorem |ipsum |dolor |si |amet."

Comment: Why use cryptic octals ?

Comment: The answer is there are no lookbehind construct in ECMAScript. regex. So, stop trying to fight with split. Use a find/find-next regex. `\S+\s?` or  `[^ ]+[ ]?`

Comment: Something like this `(\w+(?= |.) ?)`?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/WQ9EU0/4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
\b(?=\w)
```

OR

```
\b(?=[^\040.])
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WQ9EU0/5)

**Explanation:**

- `\b` - Word Boundary
- `(?=\w)` - Positive lookahead ensuring that a word character follows `\b`

OR

- `(?=[^\040.])` - Positive lookahead ensuring that `\b` is followed by any character but  or `.`

Comment: The only relevant character is the space, `\w` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @sln Provided another regex.

Comment: Here is some advice, split won't work in the case where you need a lookbehind assertion... Not in JS

Answer (score 1):

you could use split and map

```js
var split = 'Lorem ipsum dolor si amet.'.split(' ');
var result = split.map(function(value) {

  return value + (split.indexOf(value) < split.length - 1 ? ' ' : '');

});

console.log(result);
```